# The View Hierarchy Inspector does not work when debugging iMessage Extension

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch, imessage, imessage-extension

I am debugging my iMessage App Extension.

Mac OS: 10.12.5 Xcode: 8.3.2

When starting up the View Hierarchy Inspector, this is all I see.

I am not filtering any of the views with the depth control.

This happens for all View Controllers inspected and also for both the Collapsed and Expanded Views.

[image: Blank view in Hierarchy Inspector]

Comment: Is there a UI before you start debugging the view hierarchy? If so, this is a bug and you should log it with Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com . If not, what assistance are you looking for and what do you expect to see?

Comment: Yes, theres a different set of standard native UIs on each screen.  Doesn't work on both screens, in both modes (expanded and collapsed)